# Why are floating point bases even?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science

In [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) the author states that the base is assumed to be even.  Why?

Comment: Related: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Comment: The base is assumed to be even in the particular document in question, for the purpose of all proofs that are to come, in which the author does not want to have to state explicitly each time that he assumes the base is even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author may have made an overstatement, but given that bases 2 and 10 (binary and decimal) are the most common in use, it is at worst a philosophic faux pas. Per http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/why-ieee.pdf: "Almost every machine that provides floating-point arithmetic does so in binary (radix 2), octal (8), decimal (10) or hexadecimal (16). Biological and historical accidents make 10 the preferred radix for machines whose arithmetic will be exposed to frequent scrutiny by humans. Otherwise binary is best. Radices bigger than 2 may offer a minuscule speed advantage during normalization because the leading few significant bits can sometimes remain zeros, but this advantage is more than offset by penalties in the range/precision trade-off and by 'wobbling precision'".

Odd bases do happen - though in computer technology, not so much. See http://mentalfloss.com/article/31879/12-mind-blowing-number-systems-other-languages, for instance. More food for thought at http://www.math.wichita.edu/history/topics/num-sys.html.

As a side note, an odd base would make halves, quarters, eighths, etc., impossible to represent exactly, and also would make trouble for tenths and hundreths.

---

The IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754) is for binary and decimal formats only: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. Prior formats that were used over the years are listed at http://www.mrob.com/pub/math/floatformats.html.

Comment: Some even bases won't represent quarters (etc) properly either.  It would occasionally be nice to be able to represent 1/3 exactly.  Interesting.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Can you give an example of an even base that won't represent quarters exactly?

Comment: Can you update your answer to specify what the IEEE standard uses?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I meant to put "some bases" not "some even bases".  Was thinking how cool base 6 would be at the time.